# Get SharePoint Online storage allocation/utilization

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

[image: sharepoint storage utilization]

I am looking to retrieve the highlighted Sharepoint Online storage-utilization statistic via PowerShell. I see that I can get the usage and configured quotas for the sites inside the site collection, but not how to get the total amount of available storage and current amount used. What cmdlet(s) should I be looking at?

Comment: Have you tried looking at these? [Sharepoint Online Powershell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Yeah, and I actually found Get-SPOTenant, but it shows StorageQuota is 6651392. I don't know what unit that is. It clearly isn't terrabytes or gigabytes and the StorageQuotaAllocated value is 94130104. Documentation for these cmdlets seems pretty crappy.

Comment: are you sure those are the values?

Comment: That's what Get-SPOTenant returns but they don't match the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Could it be [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/get-spotenant-cmdlet-returning-incorrect-storage/68558516-a24b-4e23-b012-75b60d9199b3) perhaps?

Comment: Super. Crappy behavior for two years.